# Tasker: Switch Data Network for Different Apps

Tags: tasker

I'm planning to switch the data network to 3G for certain apps. And once I've exited the apps, I want to wait for 30 seconds before it switches to 2G again if no other 3G apps are opened within that 30 seconds.

How do I use the "If - Else" tasks to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use "if-else" in this.

## Instruction for Tasker

1. Create a new Profile with **Context** as **Applications**
2. Choose your apps in which you prefer to have **3G**
3. Create a new **Task**.
4. Add action: **Mobile Data = 3G**
5. Press back see **Profile** tab again.
6. **Long Press Task** (Mobile Data 2G/3G). A pop-up will come.
7. Select **Add Exit Task**
8. Under it, add the following actions:

   - Wait 30 seconds
   - Mobile Data : 2G

Comment: It works miraculously, thank you so much Abhioxic! However, there's a small hiccup, if I open another 3G app, it will not stay at 3G after the 30 seconds. It just stays at 2G. How should I go about this? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much!  
Did you make sure that the app is in the **Context Applications** you chose? The 2G task will and should executed only when you have exited the 3G apps.

Comment: Hi, yes I did. It's just as I exit the 3G apps, when open another 3G app, after 30 seconds, it automatically switches to 2G and stays in 2G. Did I do something wrong?